# SQL AND to see if two flags are set in two different tables?

Tags: sql, db2

```
SELECT 1 FROM
(SELECT 1 FROM mytable1 WHERE parentid = 'ID1' AND flag = 'Y') as X,
(SELECT 1 FROM mytable2 WHERE id = 'ID2' AND flag = 'Y') as Y
```

I'm making a query to see if two flags are set in two tables, where 'parentid' and 'id' are both primary keys. The query should return a row only if both flags are set to 'Y', or return nothing otherwise, then I do stuff with that result in my backend code.

I've tested this and it works but I feel like it looks wonky and could be optimized. Any ideas?

Comment: What SQL technology are you using?  How are these Keys associated between the 2 tables?   Can you create a join on them and add the logic to the where clause?

Comment: It works as expected when those columns are Unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get what You want:

```
SELECT 1
    FROM mytable1 AS a, mytable2 AS b
    WHERE a.parentid = 'ID1' AND a.flag = 'Y'
        AND b.id = 'ID2' AND b.flag = 'Y'
```

But in fact, I would prefer a query with LEFT JOIN, which always gives one row, like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.flag = 'Y' AND b.flag = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS result
    FROM TABLE ( VALUES 1 ) AS always(present)
        LEFT JOIN mytable1 AS a ON a.parentid = 'ID1'
        LEFT JOIN mytable2 AS b ON b.id = 'ID2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is fine (although I would use `CROSS JOIN`.  However, I would prefer a row with a specific value.  I would phrase that as:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable1 WHERE parentid = 'ID1' AND flag = 'Y') AND
                  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable2 WHERE id = 'ID2' AND flag = 'Y')
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) as flag
```

You may need `from dual`, depending on your database.

Answer (score 0):

It better to use JOIN instead of doing subqueries

```
SELECT mytable1.parentid, mytable2.id 
FROM mytable1
JOIN mytable2 ON mytable2.flag = "Y" AND mytable1.flag = "Y"
```

Comment: This is totally wrong -- the flag being equal to y are never what would join two tables and in SQL a single quote `'` is used to denote character strings